# Documentation for 1.12.2.Final version

Tags: quarkus

Does anyone know how to get the documentation for Quarkus 1.12.2.Final version? From the QuarkusIO page, it is only possible to get the 2.13 or beyond :(

Will it be necessary to use "The Internet Archive" for that?

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: [Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other **off-site resource** are **off-topic** for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) --- This quesiton might be better suited for the [quarkus dev mailing list](https://groups.google.com/g/quarkus-dev/) or the [quarkus zulip chat](https://quarkusio.zulipchat.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can find it from github in asciidoc format:
https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/tree/1.12/docs/src/main/asciidoc

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).